# innerHTML is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the data from the string and i want to display it in my html.

Here is the code what i tried

```
var jsn = {
        "channels": [{
            "name": "video1",
                "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "video2",
                "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "video3",
                "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "video4",
                "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "video5",
                "image": "images/bodyguard.jpg"
        }]
    };
    var id = document.getElementById("menu_list");
    var inHtm = "";
    var channels = jsn.channels.length;
    var cha = jsn.channels;
    alert("channels : " + channels);

    if (channels != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0, len = channels; i < len; ++i) {
            var item = cha[i].name;
            alert(item);
            //var name = item.name;
            var image = cha[i].image;

            inHtm += '<div class="menu"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();" >';

            inHtm += '<img src="' + image + '"/>';
            inHtm += '</a></div>';
        }
        alert(inHtm);
        in1.innerHtml = inHtm;
    }
```

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gp6xA/1/)

It is assigning the values to inHtm but my innerHTML is not getting updated. I want to display the image in my html

Comment: `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML`

Comment: `in1` should be defined, too... I guess you meant `id`, a DOM reference

Comment: what is in1 ?! where have you declared it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 in1.innerHtml = inHtm;
```

Should be:

```
 id.innerHTML = inHtm;
```

Your object is `id` not `in1` and the property is `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`.

Also I suggest using `console.log()` for degbugging instead of `alert()`. alerts are painful especially in loops, and with `console.log()` you can dump entire objects, whereas alert will just show "object".

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smRrB/1/)

Comment: if op had used their console they would probably have seen the errors!